# PHP - How can I trim a string to four characters?

Tags: php, string, trim

I am displaying a string which varies in length but I only ever want it to display the first four characters. Not sure what I need to add to this:

```
<?php if (!empty($book->editions[0]['publication_date'])): ?>
  <?php print $book->editions[0]['publication_date'] ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print substr( $book->editions[0]['publication_date'], 0, 4 );
```

See [substr](http://www.php.net/substr) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **[substr](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.substr.php)** function.

In your example, it looks like this:

```
print substr($book->editions[0]['publication_date'], 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
substr( $book->editions[0]['publication_date'],0,4);
```